# Store the grouping element in two different array in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I tried to store the first group in `@a1` and second group in `@a2`

```
my $string = "abc123def456abc321def654";
my (@a1,@a2) = $string =~m/abc(\d+)def(\d+)/g;
$, = "\n";
print @a1;
```

Result is `123 456 321 654` and then `@a2` is empty. But i want the result is `@a1 = 123 321`; `@a2 = 456 654`
For this result i tried hash , for to store the keys are first grouping and the values are second grouping but the problem is duplicates are removed. Any possible way for to do it with a single regex matching ?

I tried `eval group` within pattern matching. I get the correct result from `@a1`  but `@a2` going wrong. And don't know  what is the problem?

```
my (@a1, @a2);
$string =~m/abc(\d+) (?{push @a1, $1}) def(\d+)(?{push @a2,$2 }) \G/x;
```

`@a1` result is

```
1234
321
666
```

`@a2` result is

```
4567
456
45
4
654
65
6
777
77
7
```

Comment: Why are you trying to coerce this into a single regex?

Comment: @sorbrique I had one interview call he said it is possible with a single regex. So  im trying it for long time with a eval group yet I could not get result

Comment: @mkHun  Since you seem to strictly need it all inside a regex I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. I used atomic group and capture the result. Backtracking is problem of my second case so i used atomic groups, help to avoid the backtracking.

```
$string =~m/abc(\d+)(?{push @a1, $1;})def(?>(\d+)) (?{ push @a2,$2; })\G/x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
use List::Util 'pairs';
my @a12 = pairs $string =~ /abc(\d+)def(\d+)/g;
my @a1 = map $_->[0], @a12;
my @a2 = map $_->[1], @a12;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils 'part';
my $i = 0;
my @part = part { $i++ % 2 } $string =~ /abc(\d+)def(\d+)/g;
my @a1 = @{ $part[0] };
my @a2 = @{ $part[1] };
```

Or just skip setting @a1 and @a2 and use the data in @a12 or @part.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.12;

my $string = "abc123def456abc321def654";
my (@a1, @a2);
while ($string =~ /abc(\d+)def(\d+)/g) {
    push @a1, $1;
    push @a2, $2;
}
$, = "\n" ;
say @a1;
say @a2;

# Output
# 123
# 321
# 456
# 654
```

As a general rule, try not to presume matches are successful.  Rather than assign directly to variables, perform a boolean test ('if' or 'while) on the result of the match first, and then do the assignment.

Comment: I think this answer might benefit from an explanation of why the numbers are all ending up in the first array.

Comment: If you remove `$, = "\n"` and replace `say @a1;  say @a2` with `say join(", ", @a1);  say join(", ", @a2);` you will see that all the numbers are not in the first array.

Comment: @Marty I tried eval group with `\G`, any possible for to do it.

Comment: @Sobrique Any possible way for to do it with eval grouping?

Comment: I can't help any further except to say that \d+ will give you 456 for $2 the first time, then the regex will try again and succeed with $2 being 45, then succeed again with just 4 - because they all satisfy \d+ - but how you got '7's in there when they're not in the original string, I have no idea.  The use of anchors would stop that repeated matching.

Answer (score 1):

**Update   Added a version which does it all in regex, based on requirement clarifications.**

---

Build a hash: Key is the pattern (`abc`, `def`, etc), value is the array reference with its matches.

```
 my %h;
() = $string =~ /([a-z]+)(\d+)(?{push @{$h{$1}}, $2;})/g;
```

The `()` is needed to impose the list context, since otherwise only the first match happens, with `/g` only making it jump from match to match. See [`perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching).  Note that running code in the matching part is an experimental feature.  Instead, you can evaluate code in the substitution part.

```
my %h;
$string =~ s/([a-z]+)(\d+)/{push @{$h{$1}}, $2}/eg;
```

This is of course destructive to the original string.

The resulting hash has keys which are the patterns (`abc`, `def`, ...), with key values being array-ref with all matches for that key. You can have any number of pattern-digits pairs, not only two.  See below.

Both of these variants print the same as below.

---

*Posted initially*

This assumes a pattern (your `abc` or `def`) followed by digits.  Here the pattern used is `[a-zA-Z]`, per your examples.  You can have any number of such pairs, not only two.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "abc123def456abc321def654";

my %h; 
my $patt = qr/[a-zA-Z]/;  # for example

push @{$h{$1}}, $2  while ($string =~ /($patt+)(\d+)/g);

print "$_ => @{$h{$_}}\n" for keys %h;
```

Prints

```
def => 456 654 
abc => 123 321
```

With more than two pattern-digits pairs (added `ghi111` and `ghi222`),

```
my $string = "abc123def456abc321ghi111def654ghi222";
# exactly the same code ...
```

Prints

```
def => 456 654 
abc => 123 321 
ghi => 111 222
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I learn new things from you. But i found the answer for my question with atomic group. :)

Comment: I have no idea what the -1 is for.  The code runs and prints as shown.